# If empty string in cell in csv use other column value

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read csv file from url and print values. The next step was to get only two columns and print it. The biggest problem is that when there is `''` in csv file I should get value from other column.

```
data = requests.get(url)
lines = data.text.splitlines()
reader = np.loadtxt(url, dtype=str, delimiter=';', skiprows=1, usecols=(0, 3))

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

The example of problematic row:
`['22709' '']`

In this case I should get value from other column of file and only in that case. How could I do this in Python or pandas?

Comment: Can you share sample data from the file (both good and this bad record) and also desired results.

Comment: I cannot imagine a better solution than consistently reading the 3rd column (which will be used to fill the empty cells in the 2nd one), then combine the 2 columns and drop the 3rd one.

Comment: **Add to your question the answers to the following**. 1) Why are you doing `lines = data.text.splitlines()` and then not using `lines` 2) This `np.loadtxt(url ...` looks like it is reading a CSV file, is it? If so a) How it getting it from `url`? b) Why not just use the Python `csv` module? c) You are implying there are 3 columns then why `usecols=(0, 3)` which represents 4 columns?